# What's the reflectance of common white objects

Tags: visible-light, reflection

Let's say I have a point light source which emits in the range 440nm-630nm uniformly distributed light on a recently polar white painted wall or a piece of office paper.

What's the reflectance in average of the wavelengths of the light source of these common white objects? And more generally: What reflectance is usually needed to be sold as white and not gray? 90%? 95%? 99%?